# How to use switch case in select method? (In a lambda query)

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have 3 tables included in one model. every row has own type (enum). for every column I used ternary operatior. I cant write a method in the select query. Is there any way to do this in one easy and efficiently?
enum:

```
public enum CashBoxOperationType
    {
        ShippingReceipt = 0, 
        SalesOrPurchaseReceipt = 1,
        Collection = 2
    }
```

the query:

```
        var queryDto = query
              .Include(x => x.ShippingReceipt)
              .Include(x => x.Collection)
              .Include(x => x.SalesOrPurchaseReceipt)
              .Select(x => new CashBoxOperationDto
              {
                  Id = x.Id,
                  Date_ = x.CashBoxOperationType == CashBoxOperationType.Collection ? x.Collection.Date_ :
                          x.CashBoxOperationType == CashBoxOperationType.ShippingReceipt ? x.ShippingReceipt.Date_ : x.SalesOrPurchaseReceipt.Date_,
                  Amount = x.CashBoxOperationType == CashBoxOperationType.Collection ? x.Collection.Amount :
                          x.CashBoxOperationType == CashBoxOperationType.ShippingReceipt ? x.ShippingReceipt.IncludingVATPrice : x.SalesOrPurchaseReceipt.Amount,
                  DebtType = x.DebitType,
                  OperationType = x.CashBoxOperationType,
                  ClientDescription = x.CashBoxOperationType == CashBoxOperationType.Collection ? x.Collection.Client.Description :
                          x.CashBoxOperationType == CashBoxOperationType.ShippingReceipt ? x.ShippingReceipt.BuyerClient.Description : x.SalesOrPurchaseReceipt.Client.Description,
                  Code= x.CashBoxOperationType == CashBoxOperationType.Collection ? x.Collection.Code :
                          x.CashBoxOperationType == CashBoxOperationType.ShippingReceipt ? x.ShippingReceipt.Code : x.SalesOrPurchaseReceipt.Code

              });
```

[image]

Comment: "I have 3 tables included in one model. every row has own type (enum)." This doesn't make a lot of sense from a data-structure perspective. Can you show your tables and the relations between them? It looks like the problem could be solved with some normalisation rather then trying to fudge your query.

Comment: Can you use C# 8 or higher? C# 8 introduced [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression), which could make this code a little easier to read, and potentially answer your question as asked. That said, switch expressions may not be the _best_ refactor to reduce code complexity here - just one possible tool in the tool belt.

Comment: @melkisadek Yes, I can change  struct of db  but I dont want because cashbox value will change   when other models change . I added relation map to question.

Comment: It looks from your data model that the three options are mutually exclusive. Does the CashBoxOperationType ever change on a specific order? Can you have e.g. a ShippingReceiptId and a CollectionId in a single entry on CashBoxOperations? If I'm understanding the problem correctly then your CashBoxOperationType is just used to overcome the limitations imposed by the data model. I don't think there's a clean way of sorting this as there is no inherent order to the options.

Comment: @melikasek  Every record in the cash register is a operation, so I created the CashBoxOperationType property to not check for empty. So, on any operation "CRUD", the vault will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AutoMapper instead of assign variables to dto. You already have a dto and just map it by Automapper.

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper

Comment: No I don't agree , you can't automapper this state, because after the ToList() database query is closed then if you do you will lose performance. So we must manuel mapping

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Splitting the query can break readability and logical flow. And breaking up into too much fragmentation makes it difficult to manage. So I'll go the classic route. But it's good to see this post. I can use it where appropriate.

Comment: You don't need to split anything. You can write it however you want.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I'am going to try it , I got it :) Have a nice day